Infinite family of subtasks for a kanban board like in Trello
this is my model structure where each board can have multiple lists, each lists can have multiple cards and similarly for minitasks. The catch is i want to have each minitasks can have infinite no of of children mini tasks and and each children can have the same. So how can this be achieved here.
One approach i think is storing the children data in minitask as id of a sub minitask with no parent so that it can be created multiple time as and be fetched as long as we have its id.
Which i can store in a string, object or a json. But there must be a better approach for this right? Please guide me on how to achieve this
`model Board{
id                 String  @id @default(uuid())
title              String
orgId              String
lists              List[]
}
model List{
id                 String  @id @default(uuid())
title              String
Assignee           String
order              Int
boardId            String
board              Board @relation(fields: [boardId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
cards              Card[]
@@index([boardId])
}
model Card{
id               String @id @default(uuid())
title            String
Assignee         String
order            Int
description      String? @db.Text
image            String?  @db.Text
miniTask         miniTask[]
listId           String
list             List @relation(fields: [listId], references:[id], onDelete:Cascade)
@@index([listId])
}
model miniTask{
id               String @id @default(uuid())
title            String
Assignee         String
order            Int
description      String? @db.Text
image            String?  @db.Text
cardId           String
listId           String?
card             Card @relation(fields: [cardId], references:[id], onDelete:Cascade)
@@index([cardId])
}
`
I tried of making strings or json but managing the hierarchy became quite complex.
Does sql have a solution for this?
I have seen this being implemented in trello where each subtask can have infinite subtasks and so on
